# Multiple jQuery nav sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

How do I get both `nav sliders` working **independently**? As you can see the second `nav` buttons control the `slides` from the first `post` but I need them to work independently without having to change the `class` structure.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.post a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    showSlide($(this).index());
  });

  showSlide(0);

  function showSlide(index) {
    // Make the post__slide post__slide--visible
    $('.post .post__slide').removeClass('post__slide--visible');
    $('.post .post__slide').eq(index).addClass('post__slide--visible');

    // Set the tab to post__nav--selected
    $('.post a').removeClass('post__nav--selected');
    $('.post a').eq(index).addClass('post__nav--selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.post {
  position: relative;
}

.post .post__nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100px;
}

.post .post__nav a {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post .post__nav a:hover,
.post .post__nav a.post__nav--selected {
  color: #737d8b;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.post .post__slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.post .post__slide.post__slide--visible {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow: scroll;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__menu">
    <nav class="post__nav">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__menu">
    <nav class="post__nav">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're managing them using `classes` (multiple) instead of `id` (unique). You'll need to change the HTML/JS to modify the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display one slide only inside its slide container.

The issue your codes have:

`$('.post .post__slide')` will find out all `.post__slide` within those two div with class=post. You expected result should be only query out the `.post__slide` within the slide container which the user clicks.

My idea,

use the second parameter for [.jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to control the selector context.

**As JQuery defined:**

> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler,the search can be 
>   restricted like so: 1 2 3
>
> $( "div.foo" ).click(function() {   $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar"
>   ); });
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" ).

**The working snippet**:

```js
// first parameter: slide container
// second parameter: the index of the slide
function showSlide(slideContainer, index) {
  // Make the post__slide post__slide--visible
  $('.post__slide', slideContainer).removeClass('post__slide--visible');
  $('.post__slide', slideContainer).eq(index).addClass('post__slide--visible');

  // Set the tab to post__nav--selected
  $('a', slideContainer).removeClass('post__nav--selected');
  $('a', slideContainer).eq(index).addClass('post__nav--selected');
}

$(function() { 
  $('.post a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    showSlide($(this).parent().parent().parent(),$(this).index());
  });
  // load default slide
  $('.post').each(function(index, item) {
    showSlide(item, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.post {
  position: relative;
}

.post .post__nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100px;
}

.post .post__nav a {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post .post__nav a:hover,
.post .post__nav a.post__nav--selected {
  color: #737d8b;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.post .post__slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.post .post__slide.post__slide--visible {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow: scroll;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__menu">
    <nav class="post__nav">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__menu">
    <nav class="post__nav">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great. How do I get the first `post__slide` on the second slider to be active like it is for the first slider?

Comment: `$('.post').each(function(index, item) {
    showSlide($(item), 0);
  });` this would be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick fix and don't plan on adding more sliders you can just add another option to your showSlide function and then do a quick check on the classes.

I assumed you didn't want to edit the classes because of the CSS relations - but adding an additional class to the 2nd slider won't change how it looks.

Again, this is a quick and easy way to do this - there are more complicated ways to accomplish this and that may follow the DRY principles better.

To explain, the new classes on the 2nd slider allow me to check which slider it is in (hasClass) and then I assign (2) or ('') based on the parent's class. In the showSlide function I use the number variable to build the selector - so if it's a 2 then it targets the new classes - otherwise it adds nothing.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.post a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('post__nav2')) {
     var number = '2'
     showSlide($(this).index(), number)
  } else {
     var number = ''
    showSlide($(this).index(), number);
}
  });

  showSlide(0);

  function showSlide(index, number) {
    // Make the post__slide post__slide--visible
    $('.post' + number + ' ' + '.post__slide' + number).removeClass('post__slide--visible');
    $('.post' + number + ' ' + '.post__slide' + number).eq(index).addClass('post__slide--visible');

    // Set the tab to post__nav--selected
    $('.post' + number + ' ' + 'a').removeClass('post__nav--selected');
    $('.post' + number + ' ' + 'a').eq(index).addClass('post__nav--selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.post {
  position: relative;
}

.post .post__nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100px;
}

.post .post__nav a {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post .post__nav a:hover,
.post .post__nav a.post__nav--selected {
  color: #737d8b;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.post .post__slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.post .post__slide.post__slide--visible {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow: scroll;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__menu">
    <nav class="post__nav">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post post2">
  <div class="post__menu post__menu2">
    <nav class="post__nav post__nav2">
      <a>post__slide #1</a>
      <a>post__slide #2</a>
      <a>post__slide #3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide post__slide2">
    <p>post__slide #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide post__slide2">
    <p>post__slide #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post__slide post__slide2">
    <p>post__slide #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```